# What would cause Compiz window animation durations to not have any effect?

Tags: 10.10, compiz

Since I switched from 10.04 i386 to 10.10 x64 Compiz window animation duration settings are having no effect. What I mean is if I set it from the default of 80 to 160 or 220, the speed does not change it's always just default full speed. However it worked fine on 10.04. Any idea what would be causing this? Perhaps something is overriding it? To clarify that's Compiz > Effects > Animations. I am using the Sidekick animation.

Comment: Did you search Launchpad and/or the upstream Compiz bug tracker if anybody else saw this problem?

Comment: does this occur with other animations as well?

Comment: Did you check to see if desktop effects are still enabled in Appearance?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bug in compiz settings manager, you should report a bug by following this guide:

http://wiki.compiz.org/HowtoSubmitBugReports

Comment: this should probably be a comment

Comment: Not really, reporting a bug is an answer.